# What is equivalent of C0 in mechanical system?

Tags: piezoelectricity

[In this picture write all their equivalent Body in mechanical system and electrical circuit for a piezoelectric. What is equivalent of C0 in mechanical system?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBgZk.jpg)[image]

Comment: you'd need to add one more spring across.

Comment: Hmm, I'd rather see a dashpot than a frictional surface in the mechanical system, if it's to be equivalent to a resistive electrical loss, friction tends not to be velocity dependent, a dashpot is. Start by deciding whether voltage is force, velocity or displacement, the same for current, and where the energy is stored, and then it will become more apparent.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Answer (score 2):

Whatever mounts are holding the force source, friction plate, or the wall (if made of real materials) can be elastically distorted and thus hold potential energy.  That’s just some of the parasitics that could contribute to the equivalent of C0.

If the force source is un-anchored and mass-less, then, with any applied force, it might launch off to the left at the speed of light, and the potential energy might be stored inside something like its wave function.

Comment: Are this mean consecutive springs?in this case two springs can be replaced with an equivalent spring!